# You must specify a valid JavaScript API Domain as part of this key's configuration. in LinkedIn

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linkedin-api

I try to create a MVC4 application with LinkedIn share option with callback option.

i refer my script in my Layout.cshtml with my app id.

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
        api_key: APIkeyGOEShere
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function testme(count) {
            alert("That document has been shared: " + count + " times");
        }
    </script>
```

But the firebug shows a message like below image

[image]

But i am sure my AppID is correct. I don't know what is the reason to appear this error.

**Edits**

I place the api_key inside the single quote

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
        api_key: 'APIkeyGOEShere'
    </script>
```

But i get a different in firebug

**Error: API Key is invalid throw new Error("API Key is invalid");**

Any format need to place API key inside of the javascript.

Please help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your API key looks a bit short...

Did you just register your API key? According to Eugene O'Neill on [this forum](http://developer.linkedin.com/forum/api-key):

> After registering an API key and specifying a valid domain, it may
>   take up to 30 minutes for the changes to take affect, so if it doesn't
>   work immediately, go grab a coffee and check back in a few.

Also, make sure you specified your API Domain.

He outlines the full series of steps as follows:

> To register an API key:
>
> head over to https://www.linkedin.com/secure/developer
>
> log in and
>   click the link to Add New Application
>
> fill out the following info:
>
> - Company (choose from the dropdown)
> - Application Name (e.g. My Company
>     Jobs)
> - Description (e.g. For receiving applications from job
>     applicants)
> - JavaScript API Domain (this is an important step. this is
>     the website the button will go on e.g. http://www.mycompany.com)
> - Application Use (select one from the list, if nothing matches your
>     needs, choose "other")
> - Developer Contact Email (your email address)
> - Phone (a phone number you can be reached at if there are issues with
>     the account)
>
> check "I agree" Security text (enter the characters you
>   see just above it)

Comment: Thank you very much sir for your valuable answer... I have an API key it's created on last month. I delete my existing key and create a new application for my web application. I follow your instruction thank you very much.

Comment: Hi Sir, did you use any javascript api for sharing content in linkedIn with success call back option. please let me know when you see this. Thanks.

Comment: I have not, but I'd imagine there is. This article from 2010 is probably out of date, but it might be a good start: http://www.lockergnome.com/social/2010/12/01/share-blog-posts-on-linkedin-with-new-button-and-javascript-api/

Comment: Thanks for adding the steps, I was missing to add "Valid SDK Domains:",

Answer (score 13):

Remove the quotes around apikey. That is the problem.

Answer (score 10):

In this form:

[image: JavaScript Settings]

You have to enter your domain, click **Add**, and confirm by clicking **Update** button.

I didn't do that for the first time. And even though my domains appeared in the screen, they weren't submitted.

I run into this problem as well.

I was debugging the problem for an hour when I realized that LinkedIn doesn't save my "Valid SDK Domain" in the first place.

Comment: Trailing slash? Must or must not be present? Because for Twitter trailing slash is cause of error.

Comment: Your answer solved the issue for me. My url is with a trailing slash.

Comment: for the first-timers, click "Add", then click "Update" button.

Answer (score 0):

To add up to Paul Nowak correct [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31202897/1114926) that helped to solve my issue.

Don't forget to set correct url here, too.

Menu option

[image]

And URL here

[image]