# Linkedin Mobile Jquery oauth

Tags: jquery, mobile, oauth, linkedin-api, intel-xdk

I am new to the mobile development. I use XDK Intel as IDE and jquery HTML.

I need a Linkedin button to login th application but I could not find any examples. Can any one show me the direction please?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple examples in the linkedin documentation:

https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/sign-linkedin

You'll need a Linkedin API key to test it, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21325798/you-must-specify-a-valid-javascript-api-domain-as-part-of-this-keys-configurati).

I haven't tried it myself.