# linkedin Uncaught Error: You must specify a valid JavaScript API Domain as part of this key's configuration

Tags: javascript, authentication, linkedin-api

I have followed the instructions listed here in the 10 minute instructions: [guide](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/getting-started-javascript-api)
And the help from stackoverflow listed here: [stackanswer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21325798/you-must-specify-a-valid-javascript-api-domain-as-part-of-this-keys-configurati)

I still get this error:

Console.log error:

> Uncaught Error: You must specify a valid JavaScript API Domain as part of this key's configuration.

### My Code is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
api_key:'98eeeu4fd587w4'
</script>
```

---

Where the api_key value is the value of Consumer Key / API Key from my app.
And for the JavaScript API Domains I listed: http://mediaproof360.com,http://www.mediaproof360.com

After a day of research and trial and error I am hitting a wall.

Help is appreciated greatly. I have created a second app with credentials using that new API but still no luck.

Comment: [Configure your LinkedIn application for JavaScript SDK use](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/js-sdk) This is done by adding your domain(s) to the "JavaScript API Domains" field in your application's configuration:

Comment: @Rejeesh  look above

Comment: Just to clarify. You must use "Client ID"(found in Authentication in your app configs) as api_key value.
If you put a different value, and set correct the "JavaScript API Domains", you will still see the same error.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can try this code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key: 98eeeu4fd587w4
</script>
```

No quotes with api key will work. Add this section in the `<head>` element.

Comment: Marking it as answer may help someone else to find it easily :)

Comment: The error message totally takes you in the wrong direction. Thanks :)

Comment: So, how do I make this dynamic. In other words, I want to add a variable name as the value like: api_key:$linkedinApiKey

Comment: That's not even JavaScript, the SDK's very nasty here.

Answer (score 15):

Had the same error message thrown by Linkedn. Though my solution appeared to be different.

I didn't specify my app's domain in settings. After I added it, all started working well. Pay attention to trailing slash. It may also cause errors

[image]

Link to your apps
https://www.linkedin.com/developer/apps/.

Answer (score 11):

Adding to @Rejeesh 's correct answer above, if you happen to echo the api_key from a configuration file and have other parameters such as "authorize: true" remember to add an end of line. For example, with PHP:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key: <?php echo LINKEDIN_API_KEY . PHP_EOL; ?>
    authorize: true
</script>
```

If you don't do this you risk getting it all in the same line and you would also get the same error (your key would be invalid).

Answer (score 1):

Adding to  @Rejeesh 's and morunas's correct answers you may need to check your application java script settings and add your domain their as mentioned in Linkedin documentation

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/getting-started-js-sdk#initialize